# QML: Mid-swipe position of item in SwipeView

Tags: qt, listview, qml, swipeview, qtquickcontrols2

I'm trying to create a Parallax View based on a SwipeView element. Examples in QML documentation illustrate how to achieve it with ListView:

```
Image {
    id: background
    source: "background.png"
    fillMode: Image.TileHorizontally
    x: -list.contentX / 2
    width: Math.max(list.contentWidth, parent.width)
}

ListView {
    id: list
    anchors.fill: parent
    spacing: 20
    snapMode: ListView.SnapToItem
    orientation: ListView.Horizontal
    highlightRangeMode: ListView.StrictlyEnforceRange
    boundsBehavior: Flickable.StopAtBounds
    maximumFlickVelocity: 1000

    model: _some_cpp_list
    //Loader is used as a workaround for QTBUG-49224
    delegate: Loader {
        id: loaderDelegate
        source: "MyDelegate.qml"
        width: myScreen.width
        height: myScreen.height
        onLoaded: {
            loaderDelegate.item.logic = modelData
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this works, but instad of ListView I want to use SwipeView, since it requires less code to achieve the behaviour I want:

```
SwipeView {
    id: list
    anchors.fill: parent
    spacing: 20
    Repeater {
        model: _some_cpp_list
        delegate: MyDelegate {
            logic: modelData
        }
    }
```

Is there any way I could access SwipeView's current "x" position or swipe offset to use in this line:

`x: -list.contentX / 2`?

The closest I've found so far is `x: -swipeView.contentData[0].x / 2`, but it causes jumping over items rather than smooth transition.

Comment: You can't control the x-coordinate of items in a horizontal ListView, because the item positions are managed by ListView. The reason why you're able to manipulate the item positions in your first example is that you're not actually manipulating the delegate position, but another item wrapped into a Loader delegate. For SwipeView pages, unless you want to use similar wrappers, you could apply a transformation using QML Translate. You can access SwipeView's internal ListView and its contentX via SwipeView.contentItem.

Comment: I don't know how much it helps, but check also the ParallaxView example at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-views-example.html

Comment: @jpnurmi Geez...that's a too nice comment to just be a comment. :D Come on, let me upvote that!!

Comment: @jpnurmi Thanks, SwipeView.contentItem.contentX works perfectly. If you could move it to answer, I'd gladly mark it as correct one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't control the x-coordinate of items in a horizontal `ListView`, because the item positions are managed by the `ListView`. The reason why you're able to manipulate the item positions in your first example is that you're not actually manipulating the delegate position, but another item wrapped into a `Loader` delegate.

For `SwipeView` pages, unless you want to use similar wrappers, you could apply a transformation using the `Translate` QML type. You can access `SwipeView`'s internal `ListView` and its `contentX` via `SwipeView.contentItem`. Calculating the desired parallax effect is left as an exercise for the reader. :)

PS. See also the `ParallaxView` example at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-views-example.html.